# Which algorithm needs "visitor" (term in boost library)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I'm learning boost library in C++. And when I get to the bfs part, the guide tells me that I can input a visitor class (optional), which has functions like `vis.initialize_vertex(v, g)` or `vis.examine_vertex(u, g)`.

I think the visitor can only be used in the algorithm which you sometimes want some information that yield from it, which is uncommon. And I've only seen visitor in dfs and bfs (in boost). So I want to ask if there are any other algorithms that need visitors?

What I meant "visitor" is when you are applying an algorithm, you may need some extra information or do some extra things (such as print all elements during bfs), but not the apply_visitor in variant. What I want to ask is if there are other algorithms which we need to do these extra things?

Comment: see boost::variant. You use the values in them by visiting with boost::apply_visitor()

Comment: I've changed the question. I think the visitor in variant and the visitor in bfs is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mostly 2 kinds of visitor,

the one which is mostly application of function on "iterator":

- tree traversal (pre/post order traversal, ...).
- graph traversal (dfs, bfs, ...)

The other for dispatching on one element:

- `std::variant`
- double dispatch
- "replacement" of virtual methods (visitor pattern).